# How to create a directory in a function

Tags: bash, function, mkdir

Editing:

I'm trying to build a simple function that print out a name, then creates a directory. I'm new at building function in bash, so I have the below script that didn't work:

```
dest_path=/home/all/todo    
line="name"

mkdir_for_name() {
echo $1
mkdir $2
}

mkdir_for_name $name
mkdir_for_name $dest_path/$name
```

What is wrong with that syntax?

Comment: What is the directory that you want to create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `echo` so I believe you want to print directory name; and off course you need to pass 2 arguments to your function. May be call your function in following way. In this way you need not to change your code.

```
mkdir_for_name  "$name"  "$dest_path/$name"
```

Complete script:

```
dest_path=/home/all/todo    
line="name"

mkdir_for_name() {
echo "$1"
mkdir "$2"
}

mkdir_for_name  "$name"  "$dest_path/$name"
```

Comment: I'm trying first to echo the $name, then I'd like to create a directory...

Comment: @Bella, sure it does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses `$2`, but you're only calling it with one argument, so `$2` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a function that accepts 2 arguments, where the first argument passed is the name to be printed on screen (the "echo" line), while the second argument passed will create the desidered folder.
Passing only one argument will just print on screen that argument